# Docker-Compose - How can i scale a multi-container application?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to deploy a multi-container app that consists of a postgresql database and a tomcat service running an app that accesses the database.

My initial thought was to try the "--scale" option but this only duplicates the tomcat container.

I need to have any pair of database and app separated in their own virtual docker network and be able to duplicate this whole app environment then.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing terms here.

Scale is to increase the capacity of a deploy, that is, increase the number of replicas for the containers running on such deploy.

However, you are not looking for this according to `I need to have any pair of database and app separated in their own virtual docker network and be able to duplicate this whole app environment then.`

In your case, just launch the compose again, either changing the name (`-p`), or just reusing the same file (`-f`) from a different directory. This way you will have two different environments.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the wrong term and explaining, this makes much more sense to me now.

I think your point of _reusing the same file (-f) from a different directory_ might be my solution. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Docker designed to works with containers (container is an instance of image).
docker-compose is more like development time thing which allows you to manage multiple containers in one file with described network and etc.

in production instead of docker-compose nowadays you would use kubernetes (docker container supervisor and archistrator and etc). Kubernetes have build in autoscaling capability. But again it autoscales containers (which are called `pods` in kubernetes). And those pods are communicating with other pods through services. Meanwhile Service is accessible `name` in front of bunch of pods with same type

Thus, to the best of my knowledge, **there are no builtin way to scales pairs with network separation.**

but people are doing different stuff, like **Sidecar containers** (another container which does something to first one). if you google that you should be able to find few examples.